# no org-babel-execute function for javascript in emacs org-babel

Tags: javascript, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I have added the following code to my init file. But I still get the error.

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
      'org-babel-load-languages
      '((js . t)))
```

I noticed in [Babel supported Languages](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html), it says javascript requires [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). So I download node.js and added the folder to my Environment PATH. However, I got the same error.

So how could I run javascript in org-babel?

Comment: have a look at https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20846/17548

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for @manandearth's link, I partly sovle this question:

Reason why I got the prompt is that I wrote the wrong src block identifier in my case.

Since I write `(js . t)`, so it should like

```
#+BEGIN_SRC js
console.log("hello world");
#+END_SRC
```

Not

```
#+BEGIN_SRC javascript
console.log("hello world");
#+END_SRC
```

Possible identifiers can be found at https://orgmode.org/org.html#Languages and https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html.